# Derivative of the parameter

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have the equation$\begin{cases} x'(t)=x(t)+y(t)   \\y'(t)= \mu y^2(t)+x(t)\end{cases}$   Cauchy problem $\begin{cases} x(0)= 1 + \mu  \\y(0)=-2\end{cases}$ .

I must calculate  $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \mu}\vert _{\mu=0}$.I tried a few hours, but I can't do that.

Help me . Please

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$ a function of? It's not clear at all and completely changes the meaning of the problem.

Comment: x is function variable t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the attachments the calculus is not completed. The aim is only to show a method which will lead to the solution of the problem.This proves that it is theoretically possible to achieve it. But what remains to do would be a boring and arduous task.

[image]
[image]